# Would it be possible to build a client portal on Squarespace6?

Tags: web-hosting, website-design, cms, squarespace

I'm helping a family member set up a site which will need to include a secure client portal, providing access to documents and a simple database. I have been encouraging them to go with a more established, open source CSM like drupal or joomla, whose capability in this area is evident. However, they have a strong preference for Squarespace. Does any one know if it would be possible to accomplish this with the new developer platform for squarespace 6?

I've spent well over an hour searching google, the squarespace site and stackexchange, but can't seem to find any clear answer to this question. I'm grateful for any insight you all can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squarespace allows you to [password-protect individual pages.](http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/664507-how-do-i-set-a-page-password-) This could give you a way to create pages on a per-client basis, link to downloadable documents from those pages, and provide clients with a URL and password for 'their page'.

That is probably about as close as you'll get to a 'secure client portal' with Squarespace. (There is a [user account system](http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/412927-adding-and-managing-contributors) but you don't get to determine granular permissions such as which users can access what pages.)

You don't say what you mean by 'access to a simple database', but if you just need to capture data from visitors, you can use their [form builder](http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/569201-using-the-form-block) to do that. The form builder includes a tool to push captured data to Google docs (as well as email). You could make the Google doc public to enable others to see it if necessary.

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful information. I've been able to settle the issue.  It seems like I may have used non-standard or inappropriate terminology in formulating my question, I'd be interested to know the proper terms, if you have the time to oblige. What does one say for 'secure client portal'? By 'access to a simple database' I meant a service that would allow users to view personalized information organized according to different parameters, and to update this with new information. Is there better industry term?  In any case, thanks again!

Comment: @aBathologist The terminology was good; it was more that a 'secure client portal' and 'access to a database' are quite vague terms that could describe very simple or very complex features. It wasn't clear from your question quite what you were hoping to build.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is pretty popular. More so than Joomla and Drupal. If you need a client portal I would highly suggest you consider WordPress along with this plugin which is very affordable http://wp-client.com/